# Is the price for an adventure reduced, if you already own parts of it?

Tags: hearthstone

Adventures come in multiple tiers that each can be bought for gold or money. Also, there's an option to buy the whole adventure at once with a little discount.

If I managed to buy maybe one or two tiers with gold and then decide to buy the whole pack, will the price be reduced accordingly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it will.

From past adventures, Blizzard was reducing the price of the adventure accordingly.

[Naxxramas](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Curse_of_Naxxramas#Pricing)

[Blackrock Mountain](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Blackrock_Mountain#Pricing)

[The League of Explorers](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/The_League_of_Explorers#Pricing)

[One Night In Karazhan](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/One_Night_in_Karazhan#Pricing)

Generally speaking, the price is something along the lines of 5$ per wing. They keep the same pricing as long as it's not a single wing purchase.

So if you do plan on buying a wing with real money, buy 2. It's basically around 3$ for 700 gold.